# JS - How do you push same object value in to an array

Tags: javascript, json

I've tried a couple hours to find a way to handle JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "value": "Osteonecrosis",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
    "NamaCategory": "Primary Category",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Malunion",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
    "NamaCategory": "Healing",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
  },
  {
    "value": "Osteonecrosis",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
    "NamaCategory": "Primary Category",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Malunion",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
    "NamaCategory": "Healing",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
  }
]
```

I want to add an array Below `NameCategory` just in case the `NameCategory` value is duplicate, so the expected result would be:

```
[
  {
    "NamaCategory": "Primary Category",
    "value":[
      {
        "value": "Osteonecrosis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
      },
      {
        "value": "Osteonecrosis",
        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "NamaCategory": "Healing",
    "value":[
      {
        "value": "Malunion",
        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
      },
      {
        "value": "Malunion",
        "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
        "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm not familiar to handling JSON, so I need help here,

anyone can help me how to handling those json?

Comment: Do note your code uses `NamaCategory` rather than `NameCategory`

Comment: Can you share code that you are using to handle this JSON now?And more details on its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. This case return a new array , while creating this new array of objects check if there exist an object whose name is same as the `NamaCategory` of the old array using `findIndex`. `findIndex` will return `-1` if this `NamaCategory` does not exist in the new array. If it does not exist create an object with desired value and push it to the new array. If `NamaCategory` exists then just update the value array

```js
var orgArray = [{"value":"Osteonecrosis","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG002","NamaCategory":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":2},{"value":"Malunion","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG002","NamaCategory":"Healing","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":19},{"value":"Osteonecrosis","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG004","NamaCategory":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":2},{"value":"Malunion","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG004","NamaCategory":"Healing","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":19}];

var newArray = orgArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  //finding Index in the array where the NamaCategory matched
  var findIfNameExist = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.NamaCategory === curr.NamaCategory;
  })
  // if in the new array no such object exist where
  // namecategory matches then create a new object
  if (findIfNameExist === -1) {
    let obj = {
      'NamaCategory': curr.NamaCategory,
      "value": [curr]
    }
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    // if name category matches , then push the value 
    acc[findIfNameExist].value.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;

}, []);
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"value":"Osteonecrosis","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG002","NamaCategory":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":2},{"value":"Malunion","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG002","NamaCategory":"Healing","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":19},{"value":"Osteonecrosis","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG004","NamaCategory":"Primary Category","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":2},{"value":"Malunion","Diagnosis_Code":"DIAG004","NamaCategory":"Healing","FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID":19}];

var final = [];
data.forEach(function(e) {
  var match = false;
  final.forEach(function(i) {
    if (e.NamaCategory == i.NamaCategory) {
      match = true;
    }
  });


  if (!match) {
    var obj = {
      NamaCategory: e.NamaCategory,
      values: [e]
    }
    final.push(obj);
  } else {
    final.forEach(function(i) {
      if (e.NamaCategory == i.NamaCategory) {
        i.values.push(e);
      }
    });

  }
});

console.log(final);
```

Just loop through data and check that if element exists in final array, If exists push the value to values property, if not create a new property in the final array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  {
    "value": "Osteonecrosis",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
    "NamaCategory": "Primary Category",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Malunion",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG002",
    "NamaCategory": "Healing",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
  },
  {
    "value": "Osteonecrosis",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
    "NamaCategory": "Primary Category",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Malunion",
    "Diagnosis_Code": "DIAG004",
    "NamaCategory": "Healing",
    "FK_Diagnosis_Content_ID": 19
  }
];

//grouping by name:
//first creating a map by name for that
let dataByNamaCategory = {};
//iterating over the input array and using object destructuring to seperate the name from the other props
data.forEach(({NamaCategory, ...otherProps}) => {
  //if there's already an entry by this name in the map
  if(NamaCategory in dataByNamaCategory){
    //just push the new value
    dataByNamaCategory[NamaCategory].value.push(otherProps)
  }else{
    //otherwise create a new entry on the map
    dataByNamaCategory[NamaCategory] = { NamaCategory, value: [ otherProps ] };
  }
});

//get just the values from the map
let groupedData = Object.values(dataByNamaCategory);
console.log(groupedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

I've commented the code. Does this require any further explanation besides the comments in the code? Well, you'd have to get familiar with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)